# How to apply a folder template to more than one selected folder in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

I would like to apply a folder template to a number of folders.

I selected the folders, opened the properties, selected the folder template (e.g., Music Details) and clicked OK. When I checked the folders I noticed that the template was only applied to the folder I performed the right click to open the properties on. The other folders remained untouched.

I can't apply the template to the parent folder and use the "Also apply this template to all subfolders" option because the template should only be applied to specific folders and not all. Going over each folder in not an option because it's a large number of folders.

Is it possible to apply a folder template to more than one selected folder at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do what you are trying to do.  I fooled around with this for a little while, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Isn't it what Ablic explained in his question, saying it doesn't work?

Comment: Selecting the folders is not the problem. If I select more than one folder the template is only applied to one of them and not all as I expected.